# Getting files using adb shell

Tags: applications, adb, root-access, shell, files

I have a rooted Galaxy S4 device which runs Android 4.4.2 & I'm trying to get the files of an application using `adb shell`, when I navigate to where my directory is and get the root access in shell and type

```
cp -R com.samsung.android.hostmanager C:\Useres\S4
```

I don't get any errors but the files isn't in the destination folder, I did try to use `mv` which seems to work as the application crashed on my device but even though I still didn't get the files.
Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because `C:\Useres\S4` isn't a path on your phone, it's a path on your PC. Normally you need to use `adb pull` from your PC to copy files from your phone, but when you need root to access those files, it's not quite enough. [Izzy's answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/75555/12442) explains how to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I did that, however, when I installed the adbd insecure and enabled the insecure adbd option, it says at the current status Binary: Insecure, USB debugging: Disabled, even though I did enabled that in the developer options and now when I type adb devices, I don't get my device name!! actually I wasnt able to get my device name after installing the appplication !